# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, whm, connection-timeout

**Wordpress Website won't load. It's giving a :**

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Was working fine yesterday.

The error is appearing in all browsers, all computers I have tested in. On 2 different network providers.

Everything was up and running yesterday with no issues at all.

Cleaning the browser cache does not help.

Any idea why this is happening and what I can do to solve this?

I am also unable to log in to cpanel. guess it's connected somehow

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot connect to the cPanel or access the website from any other network and also getting a timeout error then it means you have an issue with your firewall, maybe a firewall inside the server (if that's the case you need to access the server through ssh - if possible - or console to fix the issue) or you might have an external firewall in front of the server which need to configured also to fix the issue